# Cross domain tracking (universal analytic) is not working

Tags: google-analytics, cross-domain, universal-analytics

We tried to implement auto link cross domain but it doesn't seems to work. Here is the case:

We have 2 different domains:

1. source.com
2. destination.com

When user visits source.com and click on Submit button, he is automatically redirected to the destination.com (the redirection is on the server side and not the client).
We want to have the ability to track the user action on both domains and treat it as the same user.

We have the following code on the source.com domain:

```
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXX-X', 'auto', {'allowLinker': true});  
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXX-X', {'name': 'newTracker'});

ga('newTracker.send', 'pageview');
ga('send', 'pageview');


ga('require', 'linker');
ga('linker:autoLink', ['destination.com'], true, true);
```

And this code on the destination.com domain:

```
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXX-X', 'auto', {
          'allowLinker': true
      });

ga('send', 'pageview');
```

This code is not working. we tried to use the same UA id for both but the client id seems to change between the domains and therefore I move from source.com to destination.com I see in analytics 2 different users.

We also tried to pass ourselves the _ga parameter but it also doesn't seems to work

Can anyone please advice? We can't understand what we are doing wrong.
It can be great if you can show an example code and not just reference (:

Comment: If you're doing it on the server side instead of client side, you need to be sure to add the GET parameter to the url. https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/cross-domain#linkerparam

Comment: Hi Bradly,We did sent the _ga parameter in the URL but google analytics still generated a new one instead of the using the one we passed.

Any idea why?

Comment: Wouldn't you need to require the autolink plugin before you send the pageview ?